# glob: Match files with multi-dotted extension but exclude some depending on sub part in extension

Tags: bash, grep, glob

I have a folder with tsx files and test tsx files structured as shown

```
packages
  packageName
    src
      index.tsx
      sample.tsx
      sample.test.tsx
      tests
        index.test.tsx
```

I have been able to so far write a glob pattern that matches the tsx files that looks like this: `packages/**/*.{tsx,ts}`
However I would like to exclude the test files in the glob pattern, files that have `.test.tsx`, how would I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
shopt -s globstar extglob
printf '%s\n' packages/**/!(*.test).@(tsx|ts)
```

See the [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) section in [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).